# Workflow problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I'm working with an app on Office365 and I want to implement a workflow. After that I configured everything, and did a rebuild I'm getting the following error:

> Assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' can not be resolved.  Please add a reference to this assembly in the project that is  C:...\Workflow.xaml

Anyone knows why I'm getting this?

Comment: Last time had that error was when i was working with colors programmatically. Try add the assembly to your project "using system.drawing;

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the reference of this assembly in your project and again rebuild it.

May be the the dll added in your project it not for 4.0 framework.